# Ensure code is run every time a controller is executed

Tags: angularjs

I have a state, that I go to by $state.go

Lets call the state `stateName`, associated to a `templateName`, and the `templateName` calls  `controllerName`.

I have the impression that `controllerName` does not run every time I use `$state.go(stateName)` (this impression comes from using console.log inside `controllerName`)

So far, my 'fix' is to use `$scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess' ...` and check for `stateName`. But that feels brittle: if I change the name of the state I need to alter code inside the controller.

My questions:

1) Is it true that controllers are not always called when loading `templateName` ?

2) Is there a way to ensure `controllerName` gets called every time? Or at least some function inside it?

Comment: Try `$state.go(stateName, {}, { reload: true })`

Comment: add your code of router

Answer (score 0):

One hacky solution I found is to force the $state reload option:

```
myApp.config(function ($provide) {
  $provide.decorator('$state', function ($delegate) {

    var state = $delegate;

    state.baseGo = state.go;


    var go = function (to, params, options) {
      options = options || {};

      if (angular.isUndefined(options.reload)) {
          options.reload = true;
      }

      this.baseGo(to, params, options);
    };

    state.go = go;

    return $delegate;
  });
})
```

This way, whenever you navigate the state reloads completely.